# Sugarcrm 6.5 attandane module

Tags: php, mysql, crm, sugarcrm

I Need to add one free attendance module in SugarCRM. What is the best free available module for this?  If it is not available can we build an attendance module. My requirement is to have one panel with check in and checkout button with a clock. Need to store all the attendance data (check-in,checkout, total_working_hours etc) in database as well.

Comment: can you share more details like any reference url of your module or anything ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic